# npm 3.10.10 install socket hang up error

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am using Node 6.10.1 and npm 3.10.10 on a Dell XPS 15 running Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.13.0.0-36-generic.
I am behind a corporate proxy which is configured through *cntlm*.

When I run an `npm install -d` on a project It works from a short time, and after a while I get `Error: socket hang up`.

I have found numerous questions about my problem but no solution seemed to work.

Here is an extract of a `npm config list` :

```
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.10 node/v6.10.1 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/msb/.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://localhost:3128/"
registry = "http://urlTocorporateRegistryWhichWorksOnOtherComputers"
strict-ssl = false

; node bin location = /home/msb/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/node
; cwd = /home/msb
; HOME = /home/msb
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

I **cannot** change the registry since we are using some internal modules, and I have to keep the current versions of node/npm.

I have already tried :

- Using the proxy directly in npm config rather than through *cntlm*
- Limiting my upload/download capabilities with *trickle* through the command `trickle -s -d 100 -u 100 npm install -d`

Another indication : It works on *Windows*, and I have a collegue running *Ubuntu 17.04* on a slower pc and it works for him. We think my machine might be a bit too brutal when requesting the registry. Does anyone know a way to slow npm requests ?

It used to work through yarn but some new developments have forced me to go back to npm.

Has anyone encountered and corrected this problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented the same problem, with no apparent reason, on Ubuntu 18.04.

I finally used docker with bind mounts to solve it. The steps are the following:

- Create a dockerfile with the following elements (you can also directly run with the used image if you don't need to configure a proxy like me)

  ```
  FROM node:6.10.1

  ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://yourproxy:yourport/"

  # Different RUN commands to configure npm and git corporate proxy

  WORKDIR /home/root/
  ```
- Build the image (from the dockerfile's folder): `docker image build -f npm-installer/Dockerfile -t custom-npm-installer .`
- Go inside the project folder where you would normally run `npm install`
- Run the following command to run the container interactively: `docker container run -it --network host -v </host/path/to/pj>:/home/root/pj-to-install --name custom-npm-installer custom-npm-installer bash`

You can now run the `npm install` command from the container. Careful however, you'll then need to use `chmod` on the *node_modules* folder recursively since the container uses root by default.

Another thing, if you're using node-sass, it is most of the time compiled on the fly when npm installing, and matches your OS current version/architecture. So if your linux distribution is not exactly the same than the container's you might need to recompile node-sass on your host after running `npm install` on the container. No worries though, node-sass will give you the command to run the moment you launch your application.